# SourceFile Amazon AWS S3

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to my bucket. I am able to upload with Body but not SourceFile. Here's my method:

```
$pathToFile='/explicit/path/to/file.jpg'

// Upload an object by streaming the contents of a file
$result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'     => $bucket,
            'Key'        => 'test.jpg',
            'SourceFile'   => $pathToFile,
            'ACL'    => 'public-read',
            'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));
```

but I get this error:

```
You must specify a non-null value for the Body or SourceFile parameters.
```

I've tried different types of files and keep getting this error.

Comment: It might be having problems opening the file. Try `'Body' => fopen($pathToFile, 'r')` and see if that has any issues opening the file.

Comment: `Invalid resource type` is the error I get for that method

Comment: So what does `var_dump(fopen($pathToFile, 'r'))` look like? It must not be returning a valid resource.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with not giving a good path. Looks like file_exists() only checks locally, meaning that it had to be within localhost's index.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
'SourceFile'   => $pathToFile,
```

to

```
'Body'   => $pathToFile,
```